# Markov Chain in urn with replacement

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning

> Consider a green ball and a yellow distributed in two urnas.Em each
>   step, a ball is selected at random, then if that ball is green it
>   changes of urn with probability $1/4$, and if the ball is yellow it goes
>   to the urn containing the green ball with probability $2/3$,
>   and goes to another urn with probability $1/3$. Calculate the
>   approximate probability that after 140320 steps each one contains one
>   ball.

What I think,

Let $X_t$ a Markov Chain denotes the number of balls in Urn 1 at time $t$ then the possible values of $X_t$ is $S=(0,1,2)$. Then we need to find the stationary distribution of the chain, and the probabilidade that after 140320 steps each urn contains one ball is $$\pi(1)$$

but the problem is being calculate the probability for mounting the chain
$$P(X_{t+1}=2/X_t=0)=P(X_{t+1}=0|X_t=2)=0$$
$$P(X_{t+1}=1|X_t=0)=7/24$$
$$P(X_{t+1}=1|X_t=2)=7/24$$
$$P(X_{t+1}=0|X_t=1)=11/24$$
$$P(X_{t+1}=2|X_t=1)=11/24$$
then I found this transition matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}17/24&7/24&0\\11/24&2/24&11/24\\0&7/24&17/24\end{bmatrix}$$

is this right?

Comment: It is simpler to use some symmetry: identify all ways for the two balls to be in the same urn and all ways for them to be separate. Then if for instance both are in the same urn, then you switch to the other state with probability $(1/2)(1/4)+(1/2)(1/3)=7/24$. Get the remaining three transition probabilities and then compute the stationary distribution.

Comment: More or less, except I'm not parametrizing the states the same way you are. For me your $0$ and $2$ are both $0$.

Comment: I think I agree with your analysis. But if you now identify states 0 and 2, then you get a 2x2 transition matrix instead of a 3x3, and you're left to find the normalized left eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.